# OpenERP 7 Browser Compatibility Issue in Calendar view in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, odoo

When I am trying to create leave request for multiple days using calendar view (days selected by dragging on those days), instead of one form, 2 forms open in Chrome browser. But in Firefox, it works fine.

How can I solve this issue?